# Do I need a transit visa to visit London?

Tags: visas, uk, tunisian-citizens

I'm a Tunisian citizen residing in Jordan and flying to the USA for a round trip. I have a long layover of 20 hours in Heathrow airport and want to visit London. Do I need a visa to explore London?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You might be in luck - even though [Tunisian citizens require a visa to leave the airside area of the UK's airports](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/648410/UK_Visa_requirements_Oct_2017.pdf), there's a subclause:

> Nationals of ALL countries (RED [underlined] and BLACK above) need a
>   visa to transit LANDSIDE unless they hold one of the following: (i) a
>   valid visa for entry to Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and
>   a valid airline ticket via the UK as part of a reasonable journey TO
>   that country

(Tunisia is listed in black.)

If you have a visa for your USA visit, you should be ok.  I'd check it with your local UK consulate/embassy though to be certain, as "a guy on the internet told me" isn't a threshold many customs officers respect.